# NSInferredMappingModelError when migrating Core Data store with entity that has relationshio changing from to-many to to-one

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data

I get an NSInferredMappingModelError when I try to migrate my model.

During the migration, the objects of an entity *Example* are migrated from having a to-many relationship to a to-one.

The migration fails with the error when it tries to make an NSMappingModel via inferredMappingModelForSourceModel.

I need to use custom migration because of the nature of the project - the program operates on (ideally) any kind of model.

Any ideas or nudges in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Because lightweight migration cannot deal with the change you've made, inferredMappingModelForSourceModel is going to fail.  You have to create the mapping yourself and load it with `mappingModelFromBundles`.

It is hard to go into a lot of details here without knowing more specifics but you can learn more about custom migration in Apple's [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html). You might want to start by looking at the sections "Customizing the Migration Process" and "Mapping Overview".

Comment: Moreover, if you are using custom migration, set any NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption to NO.